# Game runs in UE4Editor but not standalone

Tags: unreal-4, unreal, linux

I have just completed [these instructions](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Platforms/Linux/BeginnerLinuxDeveloper/SettingUpAnUnrealWorkflow/index.html) to build and run UE4Editor for Linux.

I created a new C++ project and in the editor I hit the Launch button and after a while it compiled and ran successfully.

If I close down UE4Editor and `cd` to `MyTestProject/Binaries/Linux/` there is a `MyTestProject` executable, but if I try to run that from the shell I get

```
error while loading shared libraries: libApexCommonPROFILE.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How do I set up the program so that it can be run standalone, not from within the editor?

Comment: If you want to launch cooked standalone game you should Package the game. File -> PackageGame->Linux.

Comment: I have the same problem. I used the package game option, does not make a difference.
Did you find a locution yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your game needs to be packaged in order to launch on its own, this way all the libraries and files are copied together.

You can do this by clicking on "File" than select "Package Game", select the platform you want to build for, in your case Linux, and select the output location.

After this the game will appear in the location you specified.

P.S. don't forget to assign to your new fancy game a cool icon in Settings, Platform -> Linux ;)